# UIButton inside Custom UIView addTarget or RxCocoa subscription not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView subclass named `AppChooseField`, which creates and holds strong references to a `UILabel` and a `UIButton` objects. 
I creates a `AppChooseField` within my `UIViewController`, adds it to the VC's view, then taps a button which is inside the AppChooseField's instance but the button is not working, nothing happens, **`flipHelp` method is not being called**.

```
class AppChooseField: UIView {

    private var button: UIButton!
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    convenience init(frame: CGRect, text: String, description: String) {

        self.init(frame: frame)
        // Factory method for creating a UIButton, which being displayed without problems
        self.button = UIButton.create(text: text, ...)

        // Factory for creating a UILabel, which being displayed without problems
        self.label = UILabel.create(text: description, ...)

        // After that, setting constraints, adding subviews etc.
        self.addSubview(self.label)
        self.addSubview(self.button)
        setConstraints()

        // ***** Not calling flipHelp when button tapped
        self.button!.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
            self.flipHelp()
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        // ***** Also not calling flip when button tapped
        self.button!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(flipHelp), for: .touchUpInside)


        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            self.flipHelp() // flipHelp is called successfully.
        }
    }

    @objc func flipHelp() {
       print("Help!")
    }
}
```

I hope my example is sufficient in order to convey the problem. Is there's something I don't understand? Is there some memory related issue which I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event does not respond, I understand that there are two situations

**1.`userInteractionEnabled = NO`**

**2. The child view is beyond the scope of the parent view**

I don't see the layout of the button, your constraints may be a bit problematic, you can change to:

```swift
self.addSubview(self.label)
self.addSubview(self.button)
setConstraints()
```

Comment: Ok that's was a hard one! The custom UIView sat inside a TableViewCell which sat inside a UITableView which sat inside a ViewController. I managed to understand that the cell was too small with the View Hierarchy Debugger, and from you of course. Thank You!